# Reading integers from a text file and placing them in a 2D array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, parseint

I have a text file with the integers:

```
6 3 4 15  
9 5 14 8  
12 0 1 10  
13 11 7 2
```

(All separated by a space)

I need to read those in using a scanner, and then place them in a 4x4 matrix.

```
    state = new int [sizeOfPuzzle][sizeOfPuzzle];
    isSolved = false;

    IODialog input = new IODialog();
    String location = input.readLine("Enter the full path of the configuration text file: ");
    File temp = new File (location);
    Scanner file = new Scanner (temp);
    while (file.hasNextInt())
    {
        int x=0;
        for (int i=0; i<sizeOfPuzzle; i++)
        {
             for (int j=0; j<sizeOfPuzzle; j++)
             {
                 state[i][j]=x;
                 x++;   
             }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you are incrementing x instead of reading from scanner?

Answer (score 3):

To read from file, change `x` with `nextInt()` method of Scanner.

```
 for (int i=0; i<sizeOfPuzzle; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<sizeOfPuzzle; j++){
     state[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
      //Choose a good name for Scanner object like sc instead of file
    }
 }
```